# Имитация нажатия на input

Tags: javascript, файлы

Есть file input, нужно, чтобы при нажатии например на ссылку `<a>Выбрать файл</a>` нажимало на input и выбирало файл. click() не во всех браузера работает, а focuc() вообще не работает, как выкрутится?

Answer (score 1):

Можно с использыванием триггера это реализовать. [Смотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tVZDk/)

Comment: библиотеки сказали не использовать )

Comment: Чего ж сразу не сказали? А JS использовать хоть можно? )) Тогда вот вам [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tVZDk/1/)

Comment: >>. click() не во всех браузера работает а focuc() вообще не работает

Comment: @ashorva, наверно... В IE5.5 не проверил, но возможно, что в нем работать не будет. Ой, бяда...  Кроме него проверил в осле версий 7+, FF, Opera, Safari. Тут, как ни странно, работает.

Answer (score 0):

И это очень хорошо, что не работает...

Принцип такой: положить поверх ссылки прозрачный input type=file, так, чтобы его координаты совпадали с границами ссылки. Получится, что клик "как бы по ссылке" будет фактически происходить на инпуте.

Comment: чем же хорошо?)

Comment: Тем, что возможность автоматически засабмитить форму - стандартная и есть всегда. Объяснять, чем это может быть опасно, если input file будет поддерживать ВСЕ события?

Comment: понял) кстати лиса поддерживает click()

Comment: Да, объяснять. Потому что поместить файл в этот инпут без участия пользователя всё равно не получится.

Answer (score 0):

> чтобы при нажатии например на ссылку `<a>Выбрать файл</a>` нажимало на input и выбирало файл

Ну так и замени ссылку на label. Зачем мудрить??

Answer (score -1):

`label for=id` не подходит? Попробуйте еще `inputEl.trigger("click")`.